# Pass configMap as argument in a Kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, openshift

I have a Dockerfile that starts a java process with this command `CMD java -jar application.jar serve /path-to-file/setting.yaml`

Now, I want to make the `settings.yaml` to be configMap, so, I can manage it in kubernetes instead of building a new docker image every time I have updated a setting.

My question is: is possible to achieve this now that I won't be passing setting.yaml in the Dockerfile but a kubernetes yaml as a confiMap?

```html
  containers:
  - name: java-container
    image: javaimage:1.0
    command: [""]
    args: ["pass the file here"]
```

is it possible to pass the file in a kubernetes deployment as configMap on `args[""]`

Comment: Did you try to [volume mount the ConfigMap in the container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you would create a ConfigMap:

```
cat <<EOF >file.yaml
[...]
EOF
kubectl create -n my-namespace configmap my-app-config --from-file=settings.yaml=file.yaml
```

Then, based on the path of the configuration file loaded in the `CMD` of your container image, you would mount that ConfigMap to the proper location:

```
containers:
- name: app
  [ ... ]
  volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volume
    path: /path-to-file/settings.yaml
    subPath: settings.yaml
[ ... ]
volumes:
- name: config-volume
  configMap:
    name: my-app-config
```